# ASP.NET MVC tightening up password requirement using MembershipPasswordAttribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, passwords, data-annotations

I am working on tightening up the password on my site, and wanted to see if I can use the `MembershipPassword`? I have tried to use the code below in my model but I am not getting any error message. Below is the password requirement, is there anything that I am missing?

Password requirements:

- 10 characters
- Uppercase
- Lowercase
- Number
- Special characters

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.security.membershippasswordattribute?view=netframework-4.8

HTML

```
<input data-val="true" 
       data-val-password="Your password must be 10 characters long and contain at least one symbol (!, @, #, $, %, ^, etc)." 
       data-val-password-min="10" 
       data-val-password-nonalphamin="1" 
       data-val-required="The Password field is required." 
       id="Password" name="Password" 
       style="width: 100%;" type="password" 
       data-role="textbox" aria-disabled="false" 
       class="k-input k-valid" autocomplete="off">
```

Model

```
[Required]
[DataType(DataType.Password)]
[Display(Name = "Password")]
[MembershipPassword(
    MinRequiredNonAlphanumericCharacters = 1,
    MinNonAlphanumericCharactersError = "Your password needs to contain at least one symbol (!, @, #, $, %, ^, etc).",
    ErrorMessage = "Your password must be 10 characters long and contain at least one symbol (!, @, #, $, %, ^, etc).",
    MinRequiredPasswordLength = 10
)]
public string Password { get; set; }

[Required]
[DataType(DataType.Password)]
[Display(Name = "Confirm Password")]
[MembershipPassword(
    MinRequiredNonAlphanumericCharacters = 1,
    MinNonAlphanumericCharactersError = "Your password needs to contain at least one symbol (!, @, #, $, %, ^, etc).",
    ErrorMessage = "Your password must be 10 characters long and contain at least one symbol (!, @, #, $, %, ^, etc).",
    MinRequiredPasswordLength = 10
)]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`MembershipPasswordAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.security.membershippasswordattribute?view=netframework-4.8.1) is not in itself designed to be used with ASP.NET MVC model validation; it is primarily aimed at ASP.NET Web Forms. That means attaching the `MembershipPasswordAttribute` directly to your model property will not automatically enforce the constraints during the model validation process in an MVC application.

You should be able to achieve your desired password constraints by creating a custom [validation attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validationattribute?view=netframework-4.8.1) to validate the password (inspired from "[.NET core validation attributes based on configuration values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61039450/6309)").

```cs
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class CustomPasswordAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        if (value == null) return false;

        var password = value.ToString();

        // Check length
        if (password.Length < 10) return false;

        // Check for uppercase, lowercase, numbers and special characters
        if (!Regex.IsMatch(password, @"[A-Z]") || 
            !Regex.IsMatch(password, @"[a-z]") || 
            !Regex.IsMatch(password, @"[0-9]") || 
            !Regex.IsMatch(password, @"[@$!%*?&#]"))
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

You can then use this attribute in your model:

```cs
[Required]
[DataType(DataType.Password)]
[Display(Name = "Password")]
[CustomPassword(ErrorMessage = "Your password must meet the required criteria.")]
public string Password { get; set; }
```

That custom validation attribute will enforce the password rules you have specified.
The [`IsValid` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validationattribute.isvalid?view=netframework-4.8.1#system-componentmodel-dataannotations-validationattribute-isvalid(system-object)) contains the actual validation logic.

---

> What about the html5 validation will this add that too?

No, the custom validation attribute in C# will not automatically add HTML5 validation attributes to the form field. HTML5 validation and server-side validation in ASP.NET MVC are two separate mechanisms.
Plus, as illustrated with [dotnet/aspnetcore issue 20717 "Is HTML5-validation supported?"](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/20717), this is not natively supported anyway.

To enforce the same rules on the client-side, you will need to add HTML5 attributes like `pattern` to your input field manually. For instance:

```html
<input id="Password" name="Password" type="password" 
       pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@$!%*?&#]).{10,}" 
       title="Your password must be 10 characters long and contain at least one uppercase letter, one lowercase letter, one number, and one special character."
       required>
```

The `pattern` attribute here uses a regular expression to enforce your rules:

- `(?=.*\d)`: At least one digit
- `(?=.*[a-z])`: At least one lowercase letter
- `(?=.*[A-Z])`: At least one uppercase letter
- `(?=.*[@$!%*?&#])`: At least one special character
- `.{10,}`: At least 10 characters long

The `title` attribute will display a tooltip to inform the user about the password rules when validation fails.

So, you will need to maintain both server-side and client-side validation if you want a robust and user-friendly system.

Comment: What about the html5 validation will this add that too?

Comment: @Jefferson I have edited the answer to address your comment.

Answer (score 1):

Can you not build a password validation class yourself? You can call it when a new user is added or user requests password change. Hoping you save passwords in the datatbase as hash or salted-hash.

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class PasswordValidator
{
    public static bool IsPasswordValid(string password)
    {
        // Check if the password has at least 10 characters
        if (password.Length < 10)
        {
            return false;
        }

        // Check for at least one uppercase letter
        if (!Regex.IsMatch(password, @"[A-Z]"))
        {
            return false;
        }

        // Check for at least one lowercase letter
        if (!Regex.IsMatch(password, @"[a-z]"))
        {
            return false;
        }

        // Check for at least one digit
        if (!Regex.IsMatch(password, @"\d"))
        {
            return false;
        }

        // Check for at least one special character (non-alphanumeric)
        if (!Regex.IsMatch(password, @"[^a-zA-Z0-9]"))
        {
            return false;
        }

        // If all checks pass, the password is valid
        return true;
    }
}
```